# armadillo c++ lu decomposition: Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

I am using the armadillo library for some really basic matrix operations. So I have a 3x5 matrix, and I want to carry through an LU decomposition.

```
#include "myIncludes.hpp"
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;


int main()
{
 mat L, U;
 mat A(3, 5); A = "1 1 1 0 0; 1 1 1 0 0; 2 1 2 0 1";

 arma::lu(L,U,A);

 return 0;
}
```

When I run this code it returns: warning: lu(): decomposition failed. However, matlab can indeed decompose this matrix.

Is armadillo extensively used and tested, or should I be careful using it?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code and it seems that it relies on partial pivoting, which is known to be stable only for square invertible matrices.

My matrix is not square, so I am out.

source : [Eigen library documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PartialPivLU.html)